# Calculate a random winner with weighted possibilities

Tags: probability

I have been trying to find a solution to this issue but so far unsuccessfully.

My problem is:

I need to write a small program to pick a horse race winner based on specified odds. for example: 4 (or more) Horses with the following posted odds: $H_1(1/2)$, $H_2(2/1)$, $H_3(3/1)$ and $H_4(8/1)$

I need to pick a random winner when running 1000 races, but biased towards the odds for each horse.

Is there a formula that I can use that can also incorporate the random element.

Hope I explained it sufficiently.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try calculating some sort of Value for each of the odds like this:

$$V_{H1} = V_{loss} + V_{win}$$
So:
$$V_{H1} = (-2) + (3) = 1$$
Continuing this:

$$V_{H2} = -1 + 3 = 2$$
$$V_{H3} = -1 + 4 = 3$$
$$V_{H4} = -1 + 9 = 8$$
Then flip the values to make them probabilities of winning:
$$P({win_{H1}}) = 8/14 $$
$$P({win_{H2}}) = 3/14 $$
$$P({win_{H3}}) = 2/14 $$
$$P({win_{H4}}) = 1/14 $$

Most programming languages have random number generators, so use them to create boundaries for each of the probabilities, i.e from $0-1/14$ for ${H1}$